# get self table column in crystal report design mode

Tags: visual-studio-2010, crystal-reports

I have a table

```
table_one
- id
- name
- p_id
```

Now, while displaying in Crystal reports, 
how do i relate the `p_id` to `id` and get the `name`
I am using in from Design mode not from c# code.

FYI : Visual Studio 2010

And I tried with `Database Expert` with `Link`, but could not link to same table

Added an image, in this `country code` are coming form database table, but how do i relate the `country name` in other table dynamically

[image]

Comment: Why don't you use Command in Database Expert instead of Table. you can add your query with multiple joins

Comment: @Shell I cannot find that.

Comment: have u checked it http://customerfx.com/pages/reporting/2009/07/31/working-with-the-add-command-in-crystal.aspx